# "Show All" (and more) not wokring in the Microsoft Store App

Tags: windows-10, windows-store-app, windows-10-v1709

When searching for an app on the MS Store, I'm presented with "Games", "Apps", etc.

To the far right of the "Apps" there's a "Show All" button. This used to work. But now on the Fall's Creators Update, it shows no apps. (If I then click on "Type" and choose "All Types" it goes back to showing all types, but as before - only shows one line of the "Apps".)

Also, when clicking on a company's name, instead of showing me all of its apps, there are no apps on the screen.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Could you include a screenshot of this?

Comment: Before clicking "Show All" button, are there apps listed? It works fine under my Windows 10 1709 machine. https://1drv.ms/f/s!Avq27-O7I1GRgxQj4uPDMbxRp8wW

Comment: @KarenHu Yes. There is a whole line of apps listed before clicking the "show all".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working now.

Leaving this for any future reader who has the same problem - maybe it'll sort itself out. It took several days. But at least now it works.